# Measure time with Python when device's epoch time is unreliable

Tags: python, time, clock, epoch

I need to count the number of seconds that have passed between the execution of some code on a Raspberry Pi. Normally I'd do it as follows in Python:

```
start = time.time()
execute_my_function()
end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start
```

However, the Raspberry Pi doesn't include an RTC and instead relies on NTP. This means that for the first little while after booting, the system time is January 1, 1970, and so the difference between "end" and "start" often becomes about 47 years.

How do I measure the elapsed time in seconds if the system time is unreliable (from what I can gather, the "timeit" module relies on "time" and thus won't work either)? It doesn't have to be completely accurate--a second or two too much or too little is fine.

Edit: I've made a sort of hack where I read /proc/uptime which I believe is independent of the system time, but I kind of feel dirty this way. I'm hoping there is a somewhat less OS dependent solution.

Comment: Probably you can wait till NTP sync is finished before your code starts running. Not sure how can you do that, but there might be a way. And one dirty way is waiting in a delayed loop till the time is not equal to Jan 1, 1970

Comment: Do you need to start the program right away after boot? Can you put a dependency on NTP? Using `systemd` or similar? You could specify NTP as a dependency.

Comment: I can't rely on NTP, unfortunately. The system is intended to run even if it's off-line every now and then, including at boot time.

Comment: @OleWolf Did you ask here http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: No. It crossed my mind to ask in a Raspberry Pi related group but I believe it's kind of a general issue related to Python on Linux rather than a hardware specific issue.

Comment: @OleWolf not really programmatic, but.. https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi

Comment: Otherwise, expecting reliable time from a system that isn't real-time won't work unfortunately.

Comment: That's actually both true and false. I certainly cannot expect to get a reliable time of day from such a system. But, say, an Arduino running at 16 MHz will provide me with a quite accurate measurement of a second within a few microseconds. If I merely need to measure half a minute's time or so and can live with a few tens of a second's inaccuracy, then this kind of time measurement is fully reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your program wait until `start_time` has a meaningful value:

```
while time.time() < 1e6:
    time.sleep(10)
```